# Xcode 8 на High Sierra (10.13.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos, mac

Добрый день. Обновил я свой мак на последнюю ОС, но не учел один момент, а именно версии икскода их совместимости с macOS. Изначально мне нужен был конкретно этот мак для работы в xcode с SDK под iOS 10.3 и swift 3 версии. Но так-то я не учел, что с high sierra идет сейчас в AppStore только с xcode 9, она с SDK под iOS 11, и полноценно работает только с swift 4. Поэтому теперь есть два выхода:
1) Возможно ли работать в xcode 8.3.3 на 10.13.1? Сам xcode app запускается, но будет ли корректно работать все это дело? Я так понимаю, что там нужно какие-то компоненты вручную подтянуть, как минимум (до этого момента я ставил xcode только из App Store). Я раньше не работал особо в xcode, поэтому не знаю, какие могут быть трудности в этом деле. 
2) Откатиться на 10.9.5 из тайм машины со свежего бекапа и оттуда уже обновится (без потери данных) до 10.12, на которой с xcode 8 проблем уже точно не будет.

Answer (score 2):

А причем версия macOS к Xcode? В AppStore всегда максимально доступная будет версия Xcode (и для 10,12 это выше 8).
Поэтому если Вы обновили Xcode до последней версии, а хотите какую-то специфическую, то просто идете на:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Скачиваете нужную Вам версию и работаете в ней рядом с основной.

Comment: Это я знаю и уже скачал с портала для разработчиков 8 версию. Но ведь из AppStore устанавливается полный пакет со всеми необходимыми компонентами, а с портала - только app и некоторые компоненты доступны только для 10.12 (напр. command line tools).

Comment: К тому же я не знаю, есть ли у xcode 8 полная совместимость с macOS 10.13.1 (например, не будет ли проблем с simulator и корректно ли работает компилятор для swift 3).

Comment: @aqu0s Посмотрите [Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW876) Если пишут "версия ОС и выше", то работать будет корректно

Comment: вот в этом то и проблема была, они в портале для разработчиков пишут только конкретную ОС, не указывая совместимости. В том числе и для дополнительных компонентов